# Typemock configuration profiler coverage

Tags: typemock, opencover

I've installed TypeMock 7.4.3 and set completed trial license, but I don't see the tab "Profilers/Code coverage" in the configuration tool. I've read user guide and TypeMock forum and found no answer. 
I need to use profile linking to integrate TypeMock and OpenCover.
Is it possible in trial version?

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer I work at Typemock.
Version 7.4.3 includes auto linking feature. Isolator detects that another profiler is enabled and links both profilers automatically.

Comment: what do you mean about "auto linking feature"? How it works? If I run TypeMock runner without OpenCover then all tests are passed. How can I integrate them? The TypeMock user's guide points to a specific tab in the configuration tool, but I don't see it in the installed product. Could you please provide an example how it should work?

Comment: @mdeg Auto linking means that the Isolator detects that other profiler is enabled and links automatically with the other profiler. In the past versions the user had to do that manually. If all the tests pass and you get coverage results that this feature works as expected. If you still need any help I suggest that you'll contact our support via mail: support at typemock.com

Comment: autolink is not working, still get the error "run tests via TMockRunner.exe command line tool and use the -link <ProfilerName>"